# Safari reloads the application when swiffy is initialised

Tags: javascript, google-swiffy

I have a `swiffy` application, it was working fine previously but after I updated to `iOS 9`, the safari reloads my application after 2-3 seconds and each time the application crashes.

The error shown is :***A problem occurred with this webpage so it was reloaded.***

On debugging I found that when I call the following code:

```
var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'),swiffyobject, {});
stage.start();
```

`stage.start()` is causing the issue. When I comment this line the blank screen loads without any error.

Please provide some work around for this.

Answer (score 2):

Cracked it!! We should remove some glyphs from the swiffy minified code. This solved my problem

Comment: Can you give more details on your solution?  Maybe a patch?

Comment: Yes!! When you convert your swf, you get a html file. In that you have an object with name swiffy object. Search into that json object you'll get many keys names  **'glyphs'**. Just delete the keys and corresponding values. The application will start working in safari ios8/9

Comment: Aren't those fonts?  Did it not affect the output?

Comment: It does not changed things for me and works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem before. I feel that the web browser may think the loading is corrupted when it directly loads a big html file. (>5MB for iPad Air 2)

I made it use ajax to load that swiffyobject and it behaves better

How big is your files? What browser are you using? What device are you using

Comment: The swiffy object is approx 4.5 MB and this issue is occuring only on iPad with iOS 9. The application is working great on iOS 8.

Comment: Don't know how to help you.

In my case, it's a as2 project converted to cross platform HTML5 site. I made a system to unload and reload swiffy objects. The largest size swiffy is 13MB. And it runs okay in my ipad and nexus 10.

Comment: @SunnyChow were you able to solve the problem of reloading already unloaded/destroyed movies?

Comment: every time i want to load a swiffy movie, i use jquery to load the json file, and create a new swiffy object